# Exporting file with even columns to different file format using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, export

I am a slight novice when it comes to VBA so I am stuck on how to make the column width look nice and clean when my data is varying while exporting to a file such as .csv, .cdc or .txt. The file format is not a huge concern to me but getting the data to align decently well would be nice.

```
Sub WriteToFile2()


    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim sOutput As String
    Dim sFname As String, lFnum As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long


    sFname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SAPoutput.CDC"
    lFnum = xlCSV
    rowCount = 1


    Open sFname For Output As lFnum
    For Each rRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        If rowCount > 9 Then
            For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
                sOutput = sOutput & rCell.Text & " ,"
            Next rCell
            sOutput = Left(sOutput, Len(sOutput) - 1)
            Print #lFnum, sOutput

            sOutput = ""
        End If
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
    Next rRow
    Close #lFnum

MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub
```

This is what I have so far and works relatively well for at least grabbing the data.
The problem is sometimes the cell will be empty in the range and then the formatting gets all messed up.

This is what I get now:

```
 ,#: ,Part & Dimension: , ,Inspections: ,Expected: ,Override: ,Sample Size: ,Complete: , , , , , 
 ,1 ,Camshaft - Circularity Tolerance , ,0 ,Tight , ,200 ,20.1 , , , , , 
 ,2 ,Camshaft - Diameter A , ,0 ,Tight , ,200 ,0 , , , , , 
 ,3 ,Crankshaft - Diameter - Mains , ,16 ,Loose , ,13 ,0 , , , , , 
 ,4 ,Piston Pin - N/A , ,16 ,Loose , ,13 ,0 , , , , , 
 ,5 ,Crankshaft - Diameter - Mains , ,16 ,Loose , ,13 ,0 , , , , , 
 ,6 ,Connecting Rod - N/A , ,0 ,Tight , ,200 ,0 , , , , , 
 ,7 ,Camshaft - Diameter A , ,0 ,Tight , ,200 ,0 , , , , , 
 ,8 ,Rocker Arms - Cam Follower / Height Screw Stackup , ,16 ,Loose , ,13 ,0 , , , , ,
```

etc...

Not really sure about the trailing commas either. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is having a specific range (A9:I25) be written into a file with even columns using a button.

Hope someone can help out I would deeply appreciate it.

Comment: If you only need to view the files as plain text then you can use fixed-width format (values would padded with spaces) - even then you need to be viewing it with a fixed-width font like Courier. Maybe you could explain further why having your data in "even columns" is important, and what you need to do with the output files.

Answer (score 0):

CSVs don't have a concept of column width. They are a datatype file not a viewing file.

Using tabs is the way to align text in columns. If you are lucky a tab delimited file may line up.

But if you want to look at data put it into Excel, Word table, or an HTML table. These programs can all print the table as it appears in the program. If you want it as formatted text use the Generic Text print driver and print to file. Or use Word's Save As Formatted Text.